# Call a factory function of anonymous class

Tags: php, static-methods, php-7, anonymous-class

I want to instantiate a [anonymous class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) via a factory function. Sadly my naive approach throws a parse error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class'` for the last line:

```
class Foo {
    static function factory() {
        return new static;
    }
}
(class extends Foo {})::factory();
```

Is something like this possible? Or is there another approach to reach the same goal?

Comment: `return new static()` with backets

Comment: `new class extends...`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. You need to return the static using `new class()` syntax (i.e. with braces)
2. You also need to generate the anonymous class with `new`

Code:

```
class Foo {
    static function factory() {
        return new static();
    }
}
(new class extends Foo {})::factory();
```

Comment: This instantiates the class twice? And so the factory has no sense anymore (because I could use the first object directly)?

Comment: I agree - what you've coded is pointless as-is. In fact, before you could create static copies of class like this you did just get the class name and create a new class.  Not sure what you're trying to do but I asked it was a cut down version of a bigger example where foo was further extended out there were static properties (in which case it would make more sense) so I just indicated the parse errors that you could apply to you fuller code.

Comment: @Robbie excuse me , but why he had to return the class with braces ? the issue is that he must instantiate his anonymous with new keyword .